# Jquery Checkbox Shift Click not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

https://jsfiddle.net/5r60uqtp/2/

If I click on the first input, and then hold shift and click on the third input why does this not select all 3?

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="grid-item">One</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="grid-item">Two</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="grid-item">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why should it have this behavior? I never seen it. And the code in your Fiddle looks far from an attempt to do it.

Comment: I have attempted to simplify this to show what I was asking.  Where I have put most of my time and attempts is in an app login area.  Will keep working on the JS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you wish to achieve...

But since a mouse event is different than a keyboard event, I may have an idea as an alternative. What if you `mouseover` the checkboxes while holding the shift key to toggle their checked state?

It would be like this:

```js
var shiftHeld = false;

// Turn the shiftHeld flag to true
$(document).on("keydown",function(e){
  if(e.shiftKey){
    shiftHeld = true;
  }
});

// Turn the shiftHeld flag to false
$(document).on("keyup",function(e){
    shiftHeld = false;
});

// On mouseover, if shifHeld is true, toggle checked state of the mouseovered checkboxes
$("input[type='checkbox'].grid-item").on("mouseover",function(){
  if(shiftHeld){
    $(this).prop("checked",!$(this).prop("checked"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="grid-item">One</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="grid-item">Two</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="grid-item">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is even better than what I was even thinking of!

Comment: Just implemented this.  I really appreciate it, and it works fantastically.